# Click triggers mousemove in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, onmousemove

http://jsfiddle.net/97o5p0ta/3/

```
<div onmousemove="m();">
    <h1>Click me</h1>
</div>
```

Clicking the element will also trigger the m() function. This can't be right, or? Doesn't happen in Firefox.

Comment: [Chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161464).

Comment: this is a good find.